# GDB Python support, ImportError no module named gdb

Tags: c++, python, linux, stl, gdb

I am trying to compile gdb with python support so I can use the PrettyPrinters provided at :
http://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python

I downloaded the latest gdb source from (http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/gdb/gdb-7.6.1.tar.gz) and compiled it on my Centos 6.4 as follows:
1. ./configure --with-python
2. make

Do I need to provide a path or another argument to --with-python with the path to python libs or executable?

After compilation when I run gdb, I see this warning:

```
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named gdb:
warning:
Could not load the Python gdb module from `/usr/local/share/gdb/python'.
Limited Python support is available from the _gdb module.
Suggest passing --data-directory=/path/to/gdb/data-directory.
```

The exception is obvious here and whatever I am going to do next is going to fail because it needs the gdb module, but I gave it a try anyways. So I added the following lines to ~/.gdbinit:

```
import sys 

sys.path.insert(0, '/tmp/pretty/python')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
```

Now when I start gdb, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 3, in <module>
  File "/tmp/pretty/python/libstdcxx/v6/printers.py", line 18, in <module>
    import gdb
ImportError: No module named gdb
Error while executing Python code.
```

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is stumbling upon this post trying to compile Python and GDB in Solus 4.1, please read the following setup guide created by me (Obviously swap out any directory names/trees to your own ones)

Set up .profile like this:

```
source /usr/share/defaults/etc/profile

# Adding variables to PATH
PATH=$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH;

# Emscripten variables
PATH=$HOME/Applications/emsdk:$PATH;
PATH=$HOME/Applications/emsdk/node/12.18.1_64bit/bin:$PATH;
PATH=$HOME/Applications/emsdk/upstream/emscripten:$PATH; 

# GDB variables


# Python variables

PATH=$HOME/Applications/Python-3.9.1/out/bin:$PATH;
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/Applications/Python-3.9.1/out/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH;
alias python=/home/jeremi-solus/Applications/Python-3.9.1/out/bin/python3.9

# GDBM variables


# GEF variables


# Various apps variables
PATH=$HOME/Applications:$PATH;

export PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH


# ... remaining .profile
```

Set up `.bashrc` like this

```
#import profile data if exists  
if [ -f "$HOME/.profile" ]; then
  source "$HOME/.profile"
#else load default profile environment variables
else
  source /usr/share/defaults/etc/profile
fi

# ... remaining .bashrc
```

Compile Python (debug build + dev (`--enable-shared` is equivalent to python3-dev)) (create the "out" directory first - then run both commands from it)

```
../configure --with-pydebug --with-lto --enable-optimizations --prefix=/home/jeremi-solus/Applications/Python-3.9.1/out --exec-prefix=/home/jeremi-solus/Applications/Python-3.9.1/out --enable-shared

make altinstall
```

After compiling Python, you can start compiling GDB. set these flags before running the "configure" command (before compiling)

```
export CFLAGS="-I/home/jeremi-solus/Applications/Python-3.9.1/out/include/python3.9d -I/home/jeremi-solus/Applications/Python-3.9.1/out/include/python3.9d"
export LDFLAGS="-L/home/jeremi-solus/Applications/Python-3.9.1/out/lib  -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm" 
export LIBS="-lcrypt -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm"
```

Note down the path to compiled Python binary. You need to pass this path to GDB configure script

```
/home/jeremi-solus/Applications/Python-3.9.1/out/bin/python3.9
```

Run configure script like this - make sure you don't close the bash shell after exporting the earlier set values!! Also, make sure earlier set `.profile` vars are set by running `source ~/.bashrc`

```
./configure --prefix=/home/jeremi-solus/Applications/gdb-10.1/out --exec-prefix=/home/jeremi-solus/Applications/gdb-10.1/out --enable-lto --with-python=/home/jeremi-solus/Applications/Python-3.9.1/out/bin/python3.9
```

Make GDB (run this from the out directory)

```
make
```

Start GDB with this command

```
./gdb -data-directory ./data-directory
```

Answer (score 0):

The CentOS 6 gdb already has Python support.  So you don't really need to build your own.

However, since you did, did you try doing what gdb suggested in the error message?

Also, did you "make install"?  You have to do that for it to work properly.

Finally, I'd be surprised if CentOS 6 did not already include the libstdc++ pretty-printers.

Comment: Tom, the system that the gdb gets build on is different than the one that it actually gets used on (we package it). In this case, what should the --data-directory point to? I haven't used that option before, so don't know which directly exactly?

Comment: Probably more important is setting --with-separate-debug-dir correctly.  On CentOS, I imagine /usr/lib/debug is correct.  You may also want to symlink some stuff from /usr/share/gdb into your install tree; maybe just /usr/share/gdb/auto-load.  But if you package it as an RPM then perhaps you ought to start with the official SRPM and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of /usr/local/share/gdb/python.
Even after "make install" I had

drwxrwx--- 4 root root 4096 Mar 16 08:46 /usr/local/share/gdb

After setting them to go+rx recursively for it and all it's subdirectories the warning disappeared.

Comment: what do I do in case gdb was not installed globally but instead resides in the local folder, like this: ~/gdb-7.12.1/ ? The folder gdb/python is present, but inside this one. How should I reveal it to python?

Comment: Which error message do you get and how do you call gdb?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to upgrade your OS version. I encountered this problem after I updated **glibc** solely. As far as I know，in other cases，old release OS could cause this problem, e.g. Ubuntu 14.04.